# exception when reloading section

Tags: ios, uitableview

When I am reloading one section,after deleting last object from array and reloading section

```
NSIndexSet *indexSet = [[NSIndexSet alloc]initWithIndex:0];
 [_LYTPhotosUICreator.getTableViewInstance reloadSections:indexSet withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

then I have an exception

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (0) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (4), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

Please let me know where I did wrong.

Comment: Update the Data source as well, While updating the table data.

Comment: Can you be specific, what your doing means deleting or adding or update of same object.

Comment: in place of reloading section, try to reload tableView for this.

Comment: from my array i deleted last object and updating that section

Answer (score 0):

`Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1` this means section 1 current number is 0, before is 4, however, you now do update section 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
// remove the objects from data source
// give the according row indexpaths
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```